# Lua format.string can't format float as decimal (%d) as of 5.3

Tags: string, lua, string.format, lua-5.3

I recently upgraded from Lua 5.2.3 to 5.3.1 but I noticed all my scripts that perform a `string.format` started failing if it tried to format a `float` using `%d`

```
local anExampleString = string.format("Sample Number: %d",10.100000001) -- Fails on 5.3.1, works on 5.2.3
local aWorkingString  = string.format("Sample Number: %.0f",10.100000001) -- Works on 5.3.1
```

Is this by design? I can't seem to find the change documented anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Lua 5.3, the `number` type has two subtypes, `integer` and `float`.

From [`string.format`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format)

> Options `A`, `a`, `E`, `e`, `f`, `G`, and `g` all expect a number as argument. Options `c`, `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `X`, and `x` expect an integer.

Comment: The design of Lua 5.3 isn't clean in many ways, f.e. math.tointeger (while tostring & tonumber is in _G), math.type (just to differentiate integer and float), math.ult (needless?), etc.

Comment: Thanks for that, I missed that completely (even though it was the obvious place to look).

I think I was expecting a more explicit note to say it had been changed from 5.2->5.3 like in [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8)