# Lua string.format ("%d") fails for some integers

Tags: lua, format, string-formatting

I am using lua 5.3.2 and the following piece of code gives me an error:

```
string.format("%d", 1.16 * 100)
```

whereas the following line works fine

```
string.format("%d", 1.25 * 100)
```

This is probably related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31577104/450836) but the failure depends on the floating point value. Given that, in my case, a local variable (v) holds the float value, and is generated by an expresson that produces a value between 0 and 2 rounded to 2 decimal places.

How can I modify the code to ensure this doesn't fail for any possible value of v ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `math.floor` to convert to integer and add `+0.5` if you need to round it: `math.floor(1.16 * 100 + 0.5)`. Alternatively, `"%.0f"` should have the desired effect as well.

Comment: `"%.0f"` is the same as `"%.f"` (a bit shorter)